# Free Calendar/Schedular Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is there any free WPF calendar/Schedular /appointment control available , I have searched on google but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this whould be a good choice  - http://wpfcalendarcontrol.codeplex.com/

And in codeproject you can find this one http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Quick_WPf_MonthView_Cal.aspx

Comment: Is any free Wpf Scheduler Controls is there? Your Kb Project has only show the appointment. but can't include a new appointment in design view itself. Any Suggestion?